# Git repo clone not working

Tags: git

When executing the "git status" command on my clone repo I get the following error:

"error: object directory /[Path]/.git/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.

error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!

error: refs/remotes/origin/HEAD does not point to a valid object!

error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object!
No revs to be shown."

This doesn't happen on my master repo.

Is there a specific way to clone a master repo so that the clone has version control as well?

Here is the config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = /CloneDirectory/.
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Here is the command I executed to clone:

```
git clone -l -s -n . ../CloneDirectory 

cd ../CloneDirectory 

git show-branch 

git checkout
```

Comment: Please explain what you did to clone your primary repo. And maybe don't call it master repo because that is often associated with the _master_ branch in any repo.

Comment: i think this link will be helpfull [Link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/object-directory-does-not-exist-git-operations-fail-after-upgrade-or-stash_home-update-650413082.html)

Comment: Add your git config file

Comment: * Added config and git commands to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

I have an unconventional setup where I have my project hosted on dropbox and I use Git to version the project. At home I work on the project on a mac, at work I'm on windows. The problem was that I cloned my main repo on my mac to a different directory on dropbox, then when I tried to use Git on windows it cause a lot of errors. When I booted my project on my mac I was able to version fine and ran into no errors.

A rookie mistake, but I learned my lesson.